# Floating div jumping into place instead of loading in proper spot

Tags: html, wordpress, css-float

I have a div at the top of my  page in the header that holds my social media icons and a dropdowncart widget. The problem I'm having is that the my two counters (facebook & twitter) initially load under their holding div then "jump" into place. I've tried everything I could think of to stop this nerve racking jump from happening but to no avail.

I'm using floats in an attempt to make the div collapse nicely when viewed on smartphones.

Website: SleepHug.com

Here's the pastebin of the relevant code:
http://pastebin.com/my0cQuPw

Here's the pastebin of the relevant css:
http://pastebin.com/c4MZAinC

Comment: Why are you including your SERVER PHP code in a client-side question?

Comment: the issue is that your page isn't rendering as fast as you'd like?

Comment: it will be hard to test without some kind of fiddle, but you can try #fb-tw {float:right} instead of left.  Basically you need to account style wise for the time it takes for the requests to fb and twitter to execute

Comment: @Diodeus I didn't think I was revealing anything private by showing that one snippet

Comment: @programminginallston no the issue is that the counters are loading under their container div then "jumping" up into proper place, which looks bad, in my opinion at least. Basically I would like for everything to load neatly in one line instead of jumping into place.

Comment: @Rooster So it may be something that can't be helped simply because of the way those two items execute and load?

Comment: If you're using only css, then nothing is dynamically changing and it's just a matter of how the page is rendering.  The best you can do is reorder your HTML as modern browsers tend to work similar to a JIT compiler.  However, there is little chance that will have a positive effect.

Comment: Write rules that make the positioning more static on those two elements.  Wrap them in a div and position that if you have to

Comment: RUSTY - it's not about PRIVATE, it's about including code that is not relevant to answering the question. It adds a layer of code that people don't even need to see.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved by rearranging the order of the elements involved as suggested by Rooster. Thanks for your help guys!